# How to notifyAll threads in a class in JAVA?

Tags: java, multithreading, static, queue, wait

Can I make a static function that notifyAll threads that are waiting in any instance of this class?

(The logic behind here is that I have queues that have threads waiting in them because they are empty and I want to finish the run of the program when calling this function)

```
queue = new Vector<T>();

 public synchronized T extract(){
        while(queue.isEmpty())
            try {
                this.wait();
                if(!active) {return null;}
            }catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        T t = queue.elementAt(0);
        queue.remove(0);
        return t;
}
```

This is the extract method.
when the queue is empty the threads go into waiting. 
I want to make the boolean "active" to false and notifyAll.

Then I will make sure the threads will not call this method anymore

Comment: Can you add your code snippet? What issue are you facing ?

Comment: I added a part of the code and some extra explanation.

Comment: No, unless you make a list of all the instances of the class.

Comment: (Unrelated, but I can already see a problem with your code (other than minimal use of braces): If it isn't *active* before entering the `synchronized` block, you may hand at the `wait`. Also, usual comment that (mutable) global state is a bad idea.)

Comment: A thread that ignores interrupts is a rogue thread which cannot be terminated.  Do not ignore InterruptedExceptions.  The best thing you can do is either declare your method with `throws InterruptedException` and remove the try/catch entirely;  or place the entire body of your method inside the `try` block, so an interrupt will cleanly terminate it.  And never ever write an empty catch block;  at the very least, call `e.printStackTrace();` in it.  You want to know the reason for your method behaving abnormally, after all.

Answer (score 3):

> The logic behind here is that I have queues that have threads waiting in them because they are empty and I want to finish the run of the program when calling this function

IMO, a better solution to your problem would be to continue using per-instance locks, but submit a *poison pill* to each queue when it's time to shut all of them down.

```
final T poison_pill = new T(...);

public synchronized T extract(){
    while(queue.isEmpty())
        try {
            this.wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e) {}
    T t = queue.elementAt(0);
    if (t == poison_pill) {
        ...My preference would be to raise an exception here, but...
        return NULL;              // ...this was in your original example.
    }
    else {
        queue.remove(0);
        return t;
    }
}
```

---

If you *really* want to be able to `notify()` all of the different instances at the same time, then you'll have to make all of them `wait()` on the same global lock object.

```
final Object global_lock = new Object();

public T extract(){
    synchronized(global_lock) {
        while(queue.isEmpty())
            try {
                global_lock.wait();
                if(!active) {return null;}
            }catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        T t = queue.elementAt(0);
        queue.remove(0);
        return t;
    }
}
```

And then somewhere else:

```
synchronized(lock) {
    ...
    global_lock.notifyAll();
}
```

Comment: I like the poison pill idea better as well. So you are saying that at the moment I want to terminate my queue I should insert from an external source (The one who is shutting the thing actually)  some fake element( the poison pill) - that will notify the threads, and when I try to extract it, if it is the pill I terminate the queue and the threads all together?

Comment: @DanBoguslavsky Both ideas are great. I like the global_lock mechanism much better, though.

Comment: @SreeKumar, It's a trade-off. The global_lock is less complicated, but it degrades the program's performance because every time an object is added to any one of the queues, _every_ consumer thread will have to wake up. Sometimes the easy solution is the one you want. Sometimes it's worth it to do the extra work to get a high-performance solution.